# Inconsistent ControlClick in Revit

Tags: autohotkey, revit

I'm having inconsistent beavhior with ControlClick in Revit. I'm trying to use AHK to make shortcuts for things in revit that normally can't be assigned. Or to press multiple shortcuts at once. When using ControlClick to do this, the button is not always pressed. Sometimes I need to press the button multiple times before it clicks.

I've tried adding Winactivate and winwaitactive but I'm still getting the same behavior. I've tried it without the text, and at diferent times, 0, .1, .5, blank. Still can't get it to be consistent:

```
F11:: ;Edit Parameter
WinActivate, Family Types, &Modify...
WinWaitActive, Family Types, &Modify..., 1
Controlclick, &Modify..., Family Types
return

F12:: ;New Parameter
WinActivate, Family Types, A&dd...
WinWaitActive, Family Types, A&dd..., 1
ControlClick, A&dd..., Family Types
return
```

Below is the original:

```
#NoEnv ;Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotKey releases
#IfWinActive ahk_exe Revit.exe ;active in Revit
#SingleInstance force ;skips a dialog box when reloading the script after editing

F2:: ;Open selected section.
MouseClick, right
send, {g}

F3:: ;Toggle Link, underlay, and pinned locks.
send, {[ 2}
send, {] 2}
send, {\ 2}
return

F4:: ;clicks on family type pulldown, works when placing families or when changing type of family in place.
click, -190, 70
return

F5:: ;Toggle leader on tag
ControlClick, Leader, Autodesk Revit
return

F6:: ;Toggle Multiple when coping
ControlClick, Multiple, Autodesk Revit
return

+F4:: ;Edit Type
click, -68, 125
return

!F6:: ;Toggle Constrain when copying
ControlClick, Constrain, Autodesk Revit
return

;Family commands
;Family Type Commands

F11:: ;Edit Parameter
Controlclick, &Modify..., Family Types
return

F12:: ;New Parameter
ControlClick, A&dd..., Family Types
return
```

Comment: While I don't have or use Revit, I do have extensive experience AutoCAD Mechanical. If it isn't the active window and I click a button (or anything really), it won't register the command but will only make the window active. Perhaps try using the `WinActive` command before the `ControlClick`. Also, I noticed that you don't have a `Return` after your F2 hotkey, which means that it will execute all the stuff you have for F3 too.

Comment: I've tried using that and WinActivate and it is still not working.Here is what I have so far.`F11:: ;Edit Parameter
WinActivate, Family Types
Controlclick, &Modify..., Family Types
return`. Thanks for the catch on the return.

Comment: You may also need a `WinWaitActive`. Since the formatting doesn't come through well in comments, would you mind editing your post with the code you tried?

Comment: I've updated the original post.

Comment: Thank you. What happens if you manually click `Add...` multiple times? Is it the same as clicking it once or does it add multiples? (And same with `Modify...`.)

Comment: It always works when I press it manually the first time. Once I click it manually I cannot click it anymore becuase a new window appears.   However I noticed that using the AHK I can open mulitple instances of that window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend trying the suggestions in the "Reliability" section for `ControlClick` in the help file, namely, using the "NA" option and/or `SetControlDelay -1`. If those don't work, I would try setting the "ClickCount" parameter to something higher than 1. Finally, if that doesn't work, I would recommend looping the `ControlClick` command on the problem-hotkeys in order to simulate multiple clicks.

Alternatively, do `alt`+`d` and `alt`+`m` work? If so, you could just have it send those. (`Send , !a` or `Send , !m`)

I don't know why `ControlClick` behavior is inconsistent in Revit, but I hopes this gets it working better.